# How can I upload a json file in jenkins workspace into a specific directory?

Tags: json, jenkins

I had written a json file which I want to upload in jenkins workspace to print the properties in json file, but file parameter doesn't seem to work. I am giving the relative path to workspace in file parameter field. Can anybody help me out?

Here's my file parameter configuration:

/resources/b2c/aem-access-automation/example.json

Here is my jenkins console output where it skips reading json file:

warning: /resources/b2c/aem-access-automation/example.json does not exist, omitting from properties gathering

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Would you please share content of yours `example.json` file

Comment: {
 "folder_name" : "/content/dam",
 "group_name" : "mc-test-group",
 "access_type" : "read_only"
}

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that your Jenkins isn't able to access that file, especially outside of it's workspace.

> ( It depends how you started that Jenkins. Is it running in a
>   container? Is it installed by apt? That case, it runs under a limited
>   'jenkins' user. Or did you just run the war file in the name of some
>   user? In that case, what accesses does that user have? ).

Anyhow it's not a good approach to tamper with the filesystem from Jenkins, not even talking about what mess file handlers can cause if multiple access attempts are made. You should solve this problem with some kind of **dependency injection**.

- Provide the file from a repository through an scm step and push it on successful execution.
- Serve the file using some artifact storage or backend service and update it through that.
- Use a database instead of a json file.

Not recommended, but if you still want to do it this way, you could just keep the file in the jobs workspace and update it there.

Comment: Thanks lenkovi. But according to file parameter plugin it must allow me to upload a file in workspace, https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: its working for freestyle job but for pipeline I am also getting error